Principal branch of $z^{1-i}$
I am solving a problem

Find the principal branch of $z^{1-i}$.

I wanted to verify my solution.
I know we can write $z^{1-i} = e^{(1-i)\cdot \text{Log}_e(z)}$
Since the principal branch of $\text{Log}_e(z)$ is $\mathbb{C} - \{z: z=x, x \leq 0\}$, it must also be the principal branch of $z^{1-i}$. Am I correct or am I missing something?

Yes it is correct although a better notation for the domain may be
$$ \mathbb{C}\setminus \left{z ; |; \Re(z)\leq 0 \textrm{ and } \Im(z)= 0\right} $$
